# Applescript works in Script Editor but not in Automator

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I'm pretty new to Applescript but have played a programmer on tv for years. The below run handler works fine but when I try to use either the replaceText() or findAndReplaceInText() handlers to replace '#' with '%23' it doesn't. If I add something like "return 'xxxx'" as the first line in the handlers then the value gets returned and everything works as expected so the problem seems to be within the handlers but I only have a thin wispy idea of how they are performing the string replace. I expect that some functionality in the handlers is possibly not available in Automator.

Thanks in advance for any help,
-pat

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set x to input
    set searchString to findAndReplaceInText(x, "#", "%23")
    set myLink to "https://a.b.c?search_string=" & searchString
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        activate
        open location myLink
    end tell
    return input
end run

on replaceText(find, replace, someText)
    set prevTIDs to text item delimiters of AppleScript
    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to find
    set someText to text items of someText
    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to replace
    set someText to "" & someText
    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to prevTIDs
    return someText
end replaceText

on findAndReplaceInText(theText, theSearchString, theReplacementString)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theSearchString
    set theTextItems to every text item of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theReplacementString
    set theText to theTextItems as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return theText
end findAndReplaceInText
```

I was expecting the '#' to be with '%23' as it does in the script editor.

Comment: Note that `input` is a _list_.

Comment: An example input would be "https://some.web.site.com/#Home/12345678"
A url encoder would be a better solution but I only need this to work on a very specific URL and the hash mark is the only issue.

Comment: You should edit the question to include that information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your workflow passes on that string to the `run applescript` action, you might try using this as the script. As the @red_menace suggests, *input* is a one-item list so you need to get its item in order to work with it as a string. When myLink is returned, it is also a list.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set x to item 1 of input
    display dialog x
    --> some.web.site.com/#Home/12345678
    set parameterString to findReplaceInText(x, "#", "%23")
    set myLink to "https://a.b.c?search_string=" & parameterString
    return myLink
end run

on findReplaceInText(sourceText, findString, replaceString)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to findString
    set sourceTextItems to sourceText's text items
    
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to replaceString
    set sourceText to sourceTextItems as text
    display dialog sourceText
    --> some.web.site.com/%23Home/12345678
    
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return sourceText
end findReplaceInText
```

You can remove or comment out the display dialog commands.

Answer (score 0):

I would be very inclined to use `sed`, the *"stream editor"* installed on all Macs:

```
set theResponse to display dialog "Enter your URL" default answer "http://some.web.site.com/#Home/12345678/#other" with icon note buttons {"OK"}
set myLink to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of (text returned of theResponse) & " | sed 's/#/%23/g'"
display dialog "Result: " & myLink with icon note buttons {"OK"}
```

---

[image]

[image]

---

You can experiment in the Terminal till you get the hang of it:

```
echo "Hello Simon" | sed 's/Simon/Bill/'                                                         
Hello Bill
```

Or:

```
echo "Hello Simon" | sed 's/Simon/Bill/; s/Hello/Bye/'
Bye Bill
```

You can read some useful examples with `sed` [here](https://catonmat.net/worlds-best-introduction-to-sed).

Answer (score 0):

> ❝ A url encoder would be a better ❞

Yes, I completely agree.  URLs are a complex crow-barring together of multiple entities that each have completely different rules for what does and does not need encoding, and how.

Of course, you *do* have a URL encoding tool, and it's called *Google Chrome*.  In fact, all web browsers do this very specialised job for us and, because this is very much within their remit—encompassing all things intrinsic and necessary for browsing the internet—they do it **extremely** well.

So, rather than using **`open location`**<sup>***1***</sup>, use *Google Chrome* and use AppleScript to create a new tab pointed at the desired URL:

```
on run {searchString as text}
        set myLink to "https://a.b.c?search_string=" & searchString

        tell application id "com.google.chrome"
                if it is not running then launch
                tell (a reference to the front window) to if ¬
                        (it exists) or exists (make new window)
                        make new tab with properties {URL:myLink}
                        set active tab index to count the tabs
                end if
                activate
        end tell
end run
```

You should find now that `searchString` can be left alone and passed in its naked form on to Google Chrome, and that the newly created tab will contain a fully encoded URL in its address bar, which negates the need to include that awful text replacement handler<sup>***2***</sup>.

---

<sup>*(1)*</sup><sub>As far as I remember, the **`open location`** command demands a well-formed URL, so it will throw an error if, for instance, it was passed something such as *`"https://www.google.com/search?q=Search For This, Please"`*.  Hence, you would also have to encode any white space if your `searchString` might possibly contain any.</sub>

<sup>*(2)*</sup><sub>This handler, which has permeated so many AppleScripts across the internet for decades, shows its age terribly:</sub>

```
on replaceText(find, replace, someText)
        set prevTIDs to text item delimiters of AppleScript
        set text item delimiters of AppleScript to find
        set someText to text items of someText
        set text item delimiters of AppleScript to replace
        set someText to "" & someText
        set text item delimiters of AppleScript to prevTIDs
        return someText
end replaceText
```

<sub>It can be tidied up dramatically, whilst letting go of certain AppleScript coding practices that were once necessary, but no longer are:</sub>

```
to changeText in this as text from something as text to whatever as text
        set my text item delimiters to {whatever, something}
        return the text items of this as text
end changeText
```

<sub>*You can of course, use positional instead of labelled parameters, i.e.:*</sub>

```
to changeText(this as text, something as text, whatever as text)
        set my text item delimiters to {whatever, something}
        return the text items of this as text
end changeText
```

Comment: I don't think your browser method works in this particular case as the '#' is not a first-level parameter of the URL. If you feed '#' to google this way, it will truncate the search string at that point; however, if you substitute '%23' then the hash character —along with all subsequent characters— will be included in the in-page search (e.g. 'search this#whatever' becomes 'search this' rather than 'search this#whatever').